# What directories does a sfdx force:package:version:create include?

Tags: salesforcedx, managed-package, 2gp

I've typically worked where there is only one root directory in an SFDX project (force-app). So I've imagined that the `packageDirectories` in sfdx-project.json act as the source/sources of the files that are included when:

```
sfdx force:package:version:create ...
```

is run as they do when a:

```
sfdx force:source:push ...
```

is done.

But with `--loglevel trace` set, it appears that any SFDX format directory in the project is automatically pulled in.

So what is a good way to to ignore specific directories when 2GP is done? Or am I misunderstanding what I'm seeing?

A bit more detail os that the sfdx-project.json is:

```
{
    "packageDirectories": [
        {
            "path": "force-app",
            "default": true,
            "package": "xxx",
            "versionName": "yyy",
            "versionNumber": "2.0.0.NEXT",
            "dependencies": [
                {
                    "package": "zzz",
                    "versionNumber": "1.14.0.LATEST"
                }
            ],
            "definitionFile": "config/project-scratch-def.json"
        },
        {
            "path": "no-ns",
            "default": false
        }
    ],
    ...
}
```

and trace messages include references to the "no-ns" folder from that JSON:

> The profile "XXXX Salesforce Platform User" from the "/Users/keithc/Dev/pe-27-jun-2022/pe/no-ns/main/default/profiles/XXX Salesforce Platform User.profile-meta.xml" directory was added to this package version.

and references to a separate "digital-experience" folder:

> The profile "${name} Profile" from the "/Users/keithc/Dev/pe-27-jun-2022/pe/digital-experience/reference-with-tokens/main/default/profiles/${name} Profile.profile-meta.xml" directory was added to this package version.

which is a surprise. Including `-d force-app` makes no difference.

Comment: Are components in those package folders actually appearing in an org when you force:package:install? My understanding is that all files/folders in sfdx-project.json are validated every command, but only the package directory that represents a package will be included in the 2GP.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, Earlier today I was seeing an installation error because a template file from what I thought was a directory that would not be packaged was included. And looking at the `--loglevel trace` seems to suggest the same thing. My assumption has been that sfdx-project.json drives what is packaged but I haven't found any clear documentation on the subject either way yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have multiple package directories, you actually associate just one of those with a given package.

Something like this:

```
{
  "namespace": "namespace",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "48.0",
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true,
      "package": "My Package",
      "versionNumber": "1.3.0.NEXT",
      "versionDescription": "Yes, this is my 2GP",
      "ancestorId": "My Package@1.2.0",
      "definitionFile": "config/project-scratch-def.json",
      "postInstallScript": "namespace.MyInstaller"      ]
    },
    {
      "path": "force-unpackaged"
    }
  ],
  "packageAliases": {
    "My Package": "0HoXX000000xxxxXXX",
    "My Package@1.2.0": "04t2Z000000yyyyXXX"
  }
}
```

Defines:

1. The package's package directory (force-app).
2. An "unpackaged" package directory that gets deployed but that is not incorporated into the package itself (force-unpackaged).

(NB: This is a sanitised version of a real `sfdx-project.json` where the material in `force-unpackaged` is most definitely not included in our 2GP.)

Importantly a package is created from a single package directory. This is how Salesforce can apply the "monorepo" approach; multiple packages defined in a single git repository by simply being sibling package directories in the one sfdx-project.json. (I do not follow the "monorepo" approach, but this simplifies handling of inter-package dependencies, when the packages are all 2GPs and share the same namespace.)

The key values are those "package", "versionNumber" and (as needed) "ancestorId" in the package directory definition; these map the package directory to a given package and allows versions to be created from that directory's content.

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ws_mpd.htm) is a bit vague but does say that:

> You can group similar code and source for an application or customization to better organize your team’s repository. Later, if you decide to use second-generation packages (2GP), these **directories** correspond to the actual 2GP **packages**.

My emphasis. A directory for a 2GP; directories for multiple 2GPs.

Additionally, you'll find information about the sfdx-project.json 2GP properties in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev2gp_config_file.htm).

Comment: Hi Phil,

If you have any good links on the subject do share. Today I feel like I'm seeing behaviour I do not expect.

Comment: @KeithC in case it helps, Dileep Burki has some unofficial notes here: https://sfdc-db-gmail.github.io/unlocked-packages/faq-unlocked-pkgs.html#simple-json  

"path (required field) - root folder where the source metadata of the package is stored in the local workspace in Salesforce DX format. The metadata in this folder is used to create the package version when the force:package:version:create command is run." If you are observing behavior different from what Phil described, it may be worth opening a Case or posting in the Partner Community.